# If $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ prove $\frac{a^4-a^2}{bc-1}+\frac{b^4-b^2}{ca-1}+\frac{c^4-c^2}{ab-1}\le ab+bc+ca$

Tags: inequality, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: a^2+b^2+c^2=1.$ Prove that $$\frac{a^4-a^2}{bc-1}+\frac{b^4-b^2}{ca-1}+\frac{c^4-c^2}{ab-1}\le ab+bc+ca$$

Here is just my thought:

After clear denominator, it suffices to prove $$\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^2)(ac-1)(ab-1)\le (ab+bc+ca)\prod_{cyc}(bc-1)$$which $uvw$ might be useful.

I tried to use pqr but it is complicated.

Also, the equality point $$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right);\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0\right);(1,0,0)$$ is a trouble.

I hope to see proofs which can be verified by hand and attained it in during competition.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: would recommend that you don't use terms like uvw or pqr without stating what they are; most people on this site are not from math competitions (honestly you're better off posting this question on artofproblemsolving.com), so people might not be familiar with the terminology you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.**

By using AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz \begin{align*}
    \frac{a^4-a^2}{bc-1}&=\frac{a^2(b^2+c^2)}{a^2+b^2+c^2-bc}\\&\le \frac{a^2(b^2+c^2)}{2a\sqrt{b^2+c^2-bc}}\\&=\frac{a(b+c)(b^2+c^2)}{2\sqrt{(b+c)(b^3+c^3)}}\\&\le\frac{a(b+c)(b^2+c^2)}{2(b^2+c^2)}\\&=\frac{ab+ac}{2}.
\end{align*}
Sum up similar inequalities, the desired result follows.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $ab+bc+ca \le a^2+b^2+c^2 =1$.
Also, $a,b,c \le 1$
So,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a^4-a^2}{bc-1} = & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a^2(1-a^2)}{1-bc} \\
\le & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a^2(b^2+c^2)}{ab+ac} \\
= & \sum_{cyc}a \left(b+c -\dfrac{2bc}{b+c}\right) \\
= & 2 \left(\sum_{cyc} ab\right) - \left( \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{2bc}{b+c} \right) \\
= & ab+bc+ca + \sum_{cyc} ab \left( 1-\dfrac2{a+b} \right) \\
\le & ab+bc+ca
\end{align*}

Hope, this helps you.

Comment: +1 Very nice proof

Answer (score 1):

Because $$ab+ac+bc-\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4-a^2}{bc-1}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{ab+ac}{2}-\frac{a^2(b^2+c^2)}{a^2+b^2+c^2-bc}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{a(a^2(b+c)+b^3+c^3)-2a(b^2+c^2))}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2-bc)}=\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{a(b(a-b)^2+c(a-c)^2)}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2-bc)}\geq0.$$

Comment: It is nice, indeed. +1